# How can I design a chaincode that invokes the same one on another peer?

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode

I wrote a chaincode1 (deployed on one peer of ORG1) that accepts the invocation from a client application and I'd like to invoke the same chaincode1 on another peer of ORG1 by using the first invocation and not the client application again. This would allow me to pass some data computed by the first one to the second one. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A chaincode can query another chaincode (or itself) without modifying the ledger **only if they both are running in the same peer**.

It can even invoke another chaincode (or itself) to modify the ledger **only if they both are running on the same channel in the same peer**.

So **it is not possible**.

Anyway, maybe you have some misconception in mind. All peers joined to the same channel get synchronized after a block has been committed, so that all of them share the same channel ledger (chain and public world state). So maybe you don't need that feature if both peers are joined to the same channel.

Comment: I need this kind of behaviour because the second needs some data computed by the first one (on input of the client). After it performed another computation, the transaction can be sent to the ordering service to be added in a block.

Comment: That's not the way Fabric works. You must think of data as belonging to a channel (or to a subset or organizations, when talking about private transactions), not to a node. Which node processes which transaction only matters for the endorsement policies, but after committing the block all nodes in the channel share the same data. And the rules above apply to calls between chaincodes.

Comment: In your case, where both peers belong to to the same organization, it should not matter which peer processes (endorses) which transaction. In the end, both peers have the same data (if both joined to the same channels). So just perform both computations in the same peer. After committing, both peers will have the result.

Comment: Yes your contribution is very great but I'd need that client C invokes on peer p1 the chain code with x (encrypted with keys of p1 and p2) and output f(x) (by decrypting with its key), then p2 computes f(f(x)) by decrypting with its private key. I can't do what you suggests because these levels of encryption suggest serialisation among invocations and going in parallel would be unusable for my business.

Comment: A smart contract should be deterministic. Its execution must be reproducible. The transaction result should only depend on the previous state and the input parameters. If your chaincode depends on the specific peer it is being executed on, then it is not deterministic or reproducible. Your approach goes against Fabric's (or blockchain's) principles. Forks weren't made to eat soup.